# Withdraw from bitcoin ATM

Tags: sell-bitcoins

bitcoin noob but here goes. I have a bitcoin address (obviously) and someone has sent me bitcoins. Now I don't have a wallet just the address (public and private) in order to withdraw from an ATM or maybe even purchase stuff? Do
I have to create a bitcoin wallet as well? Sorry if that is a REALLY dumb question but I don't know too much about this stuff. Thanks guys

Comment: Not sure what you think you have. If you have a private key, you a have a wallet, albeit one with a single address. If you don't have a wallet *app*, you'll need one to import that private key.

Answer (score 1):

By having the private key you can sweep the wallet using a desktop or mobile wallet, I recommend electrum.

If you are new to the bitcoin world, visit https://bitcoin.org that has a lot of information so you can get up to date and get out of duduas

Answer (score 0):

You're just puzzling your self.

If you want to send your Bitcoin to someone or buying some product. You will need a Bitcoin wallet or you can sweep that address funds to the destination address using e.g. electrum..

I don't much about exchange or how to withdraw your bitcoin from an "ATM" but you have to check localbitcoins.com, they can exchange your bitcoins based on your country.

Answer (score -2):

Get a wallet and import your privkey

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Short comment style answers are discouraged as they do not adequately inform an answer. Please see [how do I write a good answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more assistance.